# Xamarin Lottie Animation Ios bug

Tags: xamarin, android-animation, lottie, ios-animations

1. Description

I am working in a company where the marketing team are creating animation files via Adobe and exporting them as lottie json files for my application.

2. Problem

Most of the animation are working corectly on android devices, without problems.
But then its working perfectly on android, i had problems on IOS.

The animation has some masks to hide some falling stuff. The mask are moving by the animation. Android has no problem with it, but Ios reanders it very weird. The animation was little bit jumping and the falling stuff are stopped for some ms. So it falls not smoothely behind each other.

Comment: Is this on a simulator, or an actual device?

Comment: Can you confirm this bug on other json file? You could report an issue on Github.

Comment: @Andrew i am testig on Ipad and Iphone on real devices

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT the problem is, we are creating the Animation by our self. And no, not all animation having this bug.
And i dont know why, but the bug is only on IOS, on adnroid it is working fine.
Our Animation is working with many layers to hide some objects.

Comment: @StefanVogel Instead of writing "RESOLVED!" in your updated question, you could format the question, show the relevant code and more details about the problem and then write your own answer. You can accept your own answer and let future readers, who might encounter the same issue, know about the solution. This would help the community.

Comment: @ewerspej I edit it so i hope it is better now :)

Comment: Yes, except it's still missing some code and visuals like an image that shows the problem. You should remove the "Solution" part from the question and write an **answer** below with your findings or the solution, if it is an actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

So what we did at the moment.

We were playing with masks. We deleted some masks and created new animation which was not so complex. It works better on IOS. But after this manipulation we had problems on android :D On android was the animation no more smoothe, it was lagging.

At the end, i dont know what the perfect solution for this problem is. So we created an animation for IOS with less masks and for android with more masks. Now i am using different animation files for IOS and Android.

If i will ever know more about this, i will let you all know .)